# Удаление директории Django + subprocess

Tags: django, subprocess

В django  проекте есть кусок кода:

```
 if os.path.isdir(path_in_storage) or os.path.exists(path_in_storage):
                    subprocess.call('rm -rf %s' % path_in_storage)
```

При его выполнении в случае наличия директории выдается сообщение:
''OSError at /admin/daisyonline/book/add/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory''

Ниже следующая информация:

raise child_exception

```
     ...

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
_close_in_parent    

<function _close_in_parent at 0x7fd6e2b79c80>

args

['rm -rf /home/user/django/static/storage/BOOKS/D6F5D3CC-E89A-44A1-AD7A-0538988E913C']
```

На самом деле указанная директория существует, и при выполнении указанной команды из командной строки удаляется.
Какое может быть решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле нужно так:

```
subprocess.call('rm -rf %s' % path_in_storage, shell=True)
```

> shell=True

необходим для корректной передачи стринга в командую строку.